# Sound Hardware Only Detected After Sleep

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, sleep, sound-card

I have a Packard Bell **iMedia** from a few years back, which i now let my (young) daughters use. It originally had Vista so a few years back I put XP on it, and most recently **Win7 x64**.

### Specs

- Windows 7 64Bit
- Core 2 4300 CPU
- 4GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 7500LE(Included when purchased)
- 2x500GB HDDs set up in RAID0
- On-board Realtek HD audio

This problem only started when I installed Win7 x64. When the computer is first switched on, Windows claims `No Audio Output Device is Installed`, and when I click the speaker icon on the toolbar(to run the troubleshooter), it tells me that there is a problem with my audio device, and that hardware changes might not have been detected(see below). [Here is the sound devices registry log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-jR36jNLSWmY0o4d3dTV0taMlE). At this point there is no audio device in Device Manager, not even a `Sound, Video and Game Controllers` section.

### Troubleshoot Report

[image]

When I put the computer to sleep then wake it, then do a scan for new hardware, it appears and seems to work fine.

What is the cause of this problem?
Or is there a workaround that doesn't involve puting the computer into sleep state?

Comment: Is it using the latest BIOS version? Have you installed ALL updates for Windows and Windows 7 specific drivers from the manufacturer?

Comment: Yes to both questions...

Comment: Those were the only two things I could think of which might be causing what you described. I have not heard of it this way as much as typically hearing about things not working after waking from sleep. The only other thing I could think would be to see if there are previous driver versions which may work considering the hardware is Visa era.

Comment: The *newest* BIOS ver is from 2008, HDA is enabled. I've tried a few different drivers, but not the older ones. I will try them. But I thought it would be something more basic, the computer is not detecting the hardware *full stop* until awoken from sleep state. So how do the hardware checks at this point differ from the boot process?

Comment: You said this problem started after installing Windows 7 (x64), so that would lead me to believe it is likely something to do with software. Unless, the hardware coincidental failed when you installed the new OS. Maybe try booting to Ubuntu Live CD to verify it is working properly. Have you tried a clean install of Windows 7?